# Windows Task Scheduler Batch File - Whose permissions does commands in batch file take?

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I'm running Windows Datacenter, and I'm setting up a scheduled task to create a folder on another server on the network using the `md` command.  Here is my setup.  I have 'user A' who has access to log into the server, but does not have permissions to create tasks in Task Scheduler.  I also have 'user B' who does not have permissions to log into the server, but does have permissions to create scheduled tasks.

I've created a task with 'User A' as the author with security settings of `When running the task, use the following user account: User B`.

The action looks like this:

`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe  /c "C:\test.bat"`

with the Program/script as

`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

and the arguments of

`/c "C:\test.bat"`

It doesn't look like the batch file is working.  When this batch file is being called by Task Scheduler, who is actually performing the `md` command, User A (login but no task) or User B (no login but task).  I assume if it's User B then that could be the problem, that User B may not have permissions to write to the other server.  Any insight you all could provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task will run as User B which unfortunately will cause issues regarding permissions.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.  I have the scenario I have entered, and there isn't an option to deviate from that.  I can't run as SYSTEM.

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you wanted an alternative apologies! the answer to your question is yes it will run as User B and yes that will cause issues if he doesnt have permissions on the server.

Comment: If you would like to edit your answer above to reflect this comment, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted!